# How to unbind escape with change session

Tags: macos, tmux, macos-sonoma, sonoma

My config with attempts, i try to change with unbind and unbind-key and this doesnt work, i cant use escape in neovim btw.

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind C-a send-prefix

bind s choose-tree -sZ -O name

set -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1

unbind %
bind = split-window -h 

unbind '"'
bind - split-window -v

bind-key -n C-t new-window
bind-key -n C-w kill-window
bind-key -n C-q next-window
# this doesnt work
unbind-key Escape
unbind Escape
bind-key -T root C-[ switch-client -n
# this ok
bind-key -n C-[ switch-client -n
bind-key -n C-] switch-client -p

bind -n C-e choose-tree

unbind r
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

set -g mouse on

set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
set -g @plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
set -g @plugin 'jimeh/tmux-themepack'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect' 
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum'

set -g @themepack 'powerline/default/blue'

set -g @resurrect-capture-pane-contents 'on'
set -g @continuum-restore 'on'

run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
`
```

I try to change escape keybind to another, and it doesnt work, I use macos sonoma, nvim latest version

Comment: program is iterm2